# how to configure CKDIV8 fuse on AVR programming

Tags: c, avr, fuse, atmega

I use atmega168a and configure fuse on Tools > device programming > AVR dragon > fuses > (click on) CKDIV8 to set it to 8 MHz internal clock.

what piece of code do I need to add to my C code to be able to set that fuse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If you set the fuse externally, as a separate step, you don't need any further code in C.
- If you set the fuse programmatically, you don't need to set the fuse externally. Now (each) program decides, at run-time. This code is for atmega32u2:

> CLKPR = 1 << CLKPCE;
>   // Set prescaler to 1
>   CLKPR = 0;

---

In both cases, you should set `F_CPU`:

```
#define F_CPU 8000000ul
```

in your source or even better as `CFLAGS`

> CFLAGS += -DF_CPU=8000000ul

in your `Makefile`, so that others knows about the core frequency: `_delay_ms` in `<util/delay.h>`, for example.